# Library's types not correctly reflecting in JS file

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am importing a simple JS file via `script` tag on an HTML page.

As I use jQuery on the website I've added `// @ts-check` to the top of the JS file, as well as jQuery types:

```
/**
 * Modal Functionality
 * @param {JQueryStatic} $ Provides jQuery types
 */
const example = ($) => ...
```

While jQuery types are correctly cast to `$`, I'm also using the `Swiper` library and include the library's JS via another script tag. For the sake of argument this could be any other externally imported library.

When using `new Swiper('...')` in the JS, TS scribbles lines underneath Swiper: `Cannot find name 'Swiper'`. I've added the following code to an adjacent TS file:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Swiper: typeof import('swiper'); // swiper types imported from official package
    }
}

let Swiper = window.Swiper;
```

Going back to my JS file, hovering over Swiper still reads `Swiper: any`. Shouldn't it reflect the types found from the imported package? Is the JS/TS file structure a problem? How do I get type annotations in a JS file?

Answer (score 0):

Some library include types, some not. You need to install types for Swiper.

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/swiper
```

After this you can import type in ts file

```js
// index.d.ts
import Swiper from 'swiper';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        Swiper: Swiper;
    }
}
```

[image: Now I have correctly defined types]

### [Update 1]

Typescript look global type declaration by default at index.d.ts file.
To declare modules or extend window and global properties, you need to declare them in `index.d.ts`.

### How to solve your issue:

1. Create file index.d.ts in root of project (if you haven`t tsconfig.json file).
2. Declare Swiper as shown abobe.

Comment: This did not work. I already have the Swiper types installed. I tried declaring the global variable in a theme.d.ts file, as well as theme.ts file, while the actual javascript resides in theme.js. I still get the error `Cannot find name 'Swiper'`. Isn't the way I imported it the same as how you imported it?

Comment: Could you provide tsconfig.json?

Comment: I don't have one. Just using VSCode and typescript@4.4.4. If you think I need one, what defaults should be in it in context of your answer to the post?

Comment: Thank you for your update. Again didn't work. I moved the index.d.ts from my JS folder to the root folder of the project. TS is installed a few folders higher up. Still getting 'Cannot find name Swiper'.

Comment: @Hewe can you provide your project structure (folders, package.json and index.d.ts and js source code location) and which folder you open in VSCode?

Comment: Open root folder, containing index.d.ts, package.json, node_modules, js folder. Open JS folder from root where you find the index.js. It looks like what you've described